# Decompressing and Compressing a Zip/GZip Stream in JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, zip, gzip

I want to exchange compressed streams between a client and a server and I am asking myself if there is a chance to read and write arrays compressed / decompressed using GZIPInputStream or ZipInputStream. I do not want to port my own compression library.

I might get the default java implementation of those classes to be translated by GWT but before I spend two days on this, is there any default library? I saw libs for zipping / unzipping files in JS but I would rather have a byte array transformed in another byte array.

Comment: Your browser and server are almost certainly already gzipping things en route for you. If they aren't, fix the server configuration so they do.

Comment: You must add the header `Content-Encoding: gzip` to your `gzip` compressed files. Browsers will automatically decompress them.

Comment: I know the content encoding. What I have are precompressed data that I want to send to servers and devices. Decompressing and let the server compress it makes no sense especially if you send those to a hundred devices independently the same time. So having control about the decompression / compression capabilities in JavaScript would be great.